# How can I start an instance of my API project and keep it running while I start and stop my Blazor web project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, blazor

I have a solution in Visual Studio that has an API project and a Blazor web project. Every time I make a change and start up my Blazor project I have to manually start up my API project, because the Blazor project makes calls to the API.

How can I start the API and keep it running? Every time I stop my Blazor project the API project also stops.

Both are running IIS Express.

Comment: If you don't need to debug the API project, you can launch it without debugging (CTRL+F5) this will launch it in IIS Express, and won't be stopped when you stop debugging the Blazor project

Comment: @Alex that was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@Alex was correct. I knew it was something simple.

> If you don't need to debug the API project, you can launch it without
> debugging (CTRL+F5) this will launch it in IIS Express, and won't be
> stopped when you stop debugging the Blazor project